# Android & JNI how to pass an array of Byte[] data to JNI and get back Byte []

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I want to pass byte[] data (frame) captured by a camera to JNI part. I need some frames to pass at once, so I am thinking whether I can create a byte[][] to store the byte[] so that I can get byte[] back from JNI. Is it possible? I know that `getByteArrayElement()` might help. Does anyone know how to achieve it?

Actually, I have tried using queue to achieve the purpose of passing byte[] before, but it seems impossible to do it as some people answered me.

Past code (Put byte[] into arraylist):

```
aCamera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback(){
            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                synchronized (TestClass.this){
                    AFrame = data;
                    int i = 0;
                    queue = new ArrayList<byte[]>(definedSize);

                    if(queue.size()<definedSize){
                    queue.add(data);
                    }
                    else{
                        queue.remove(0);
                    }
                    TestClass.this.notify();
                }
            }

        });
```

Arraylist cannot get back in JNI so this time I am thinking whether I can do it with another byte array.

I am very new to android app development with native method. Can anyone give me some suggestion? I just want to know whether this is a possible approach.

Comment: `Byte[]` or `byte[]`? And if the first, why? Why not a `byte` array?

Comment: Sorry, it should by byte[], but I want to treat it as a data and store it inside another array

Answer (score 2):

JNI is the Java Native Interface. It defines a way for managed code (written in the Java programming language) to interact with native code (written in C/C++). It's vendor-neutral, has support for loading code from dynamic shared libraries, and while cumbersome at times is reasonably efficient.

I think following code will help you ::

```
void Java_MyClass_Solution(JNIEnv* env, jobject, jobject input, jobjectArray output)
{
    jsize nThumbnails = env->GetArrayLength(output) - 1;
    void* inputPtr = env->GetDirectBufferAddress(input);
    jlong inputLength = env->GetDirectBufferCapacity(input);

    // ...

    void* hash = ...; // a pointer to the hash data
    int hashDataLength = ...;
    void** thumbnails = ...; // an array of pointers, each one points to thumbnail data
    int* thumbnailDataLengths = ...; // an array of ints, each one is the length of the thumbnail data with the same index

    jobject hashBuffer = env->NewDirectByteBuffer(hash, hashDataLength);
    env->SetObjectArrayElement(output, 0, hashBuffer);

    for (int i = 0; i < nThumbnails; i++)
        env->SetObjectArrayElement(output, i + 1, env->NewDirectByteBuffer(thumbnails[i], thumbnailDataLengths[i]));
}
```

Pleasee the further details [here](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#region_calls)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I feel confused for your code, could you please give some explanation.

Comment: As I don't know the relation between your code and the way that passing byte[][] to JNI and get byte[] back

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#region_calls

Comment: Thank you very much and I think I need to put much time to study it.